# A Heroic Narrative of two

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, movies, literature

We two were the **ones**
destined to do great things
We started as did Jon
aware of Nothing

A world we didn't know
turned out to be our home
Waited where we were
with glorious foretellings
While everyone believed
we thought ourselves a regular Joe
Otherwise the future revealed
A destiny for us each

Closer to our nemesis
than others we were
Entwined with their life
Our deaths were
I marked him, He marked me
The death of them, incident seemed to be
But not all was revealed
to the four of us it was
A great transfer of power
though unintentional it was

Helped us to the end
our mentors did
But not everything of our end
tell us they did
Their own end they met
too very soon
But even then a part
remained to be seen

Alone at last
against our enemy we were
Sure of our fate
we sacrificed ourself
Similar though it seems
Not the same it is
Because here at the end
the difference is revealed
I was resurrected,
But I couldn't do it again

I didn't know him, he didn't know me
A verse different we turn out to be

Before/after the end
our mentors did reappear
Do guess our names
Please do it dear.

Hint:

> Go fictional

There are a lot of hints scattered in the comments, consolidating it all here :

> 'four of us' - 2 heroes, and their nemesis each
>
> Jon is a reference, Our heroes didn't know anything at the start like Jon
>
> Sadly its not GOT, Fight Club, Lord of the Rings or Star Wars(I wish!!)
>
> Heroes do not share the name(there was a typo earlier)
>
> One of the heroes has been found!! Look at the answer by Gareth
>
> Title might just give you a clue
>
> Heroes are usually talking about them both, but not always. The 
>      distinction is made clear whenever that's the case.

Another hint:

> our heroes are usually referred to in their world by a phrase, with one word  in common. That word is present in the riddle and gives you a very direct 
>  clue to their identity. Look to the start!!

Comment: **Jon -> Jon Snow -> You know nothing** I think the answer might be a trivial one here

Comment: Jon is Jon snow, But that's merely a hint, not the answer. The two, like Jon, knew nothing. Besides, Jon wont fit every line.

Comment: I believe this could be arya and sansa stark

Comment: They dont fit every line. The story might partially satisfy many a heroes, since they have a similar arc, but only two will satisfy each and every line

Comment: I'm not much into the GoT universe, I don't really know too many of the characters, unfortunately.

Comment: All you need to know from GoT for this puzzle is that Jon knows nothing

Comment: This is infuriating me (in a good way)...  So many ideas that fit brilliantly in places but fall flat elsewhere... the first verse could definitely makes you think GoT, the second and third verses could easily be about harry potter, the fourth is what made me think starwars, the fifth could be anything...  I'm confused! +1

Comment: Hmm. Look to the title, a clue you may find. I shouldn't say any more, or I might just answer mine.

Comment: Isn't this trivia? Of course, it has some metaphorical ideas yet the answer relies on the knowledge of fictional stories...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the light of the most recent hints, it seems clear that the pair we are actually looking for is

> Harry Potter and Neo from *The Matrix*.

Here are some details.

We two were the ones
destined to do great things

> There was a prophecy and all.

We started as did Jon
aware of Nothing

> At the start of *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* Harry is living under the Dursleys' stairs and has no idea magic is real. At the start of *The Matrix* Neo is still called Thomas Anderson and living in the Matrix, and has no idea (beyond a few un-understood rumours) of what his world really is.

A world we didn't know
turned out to be our home

> For Harry, the world of magic and wizards. For Neo, the world outside the Matrix.

Waited where we were
with glorious foretellings
While everyone believed
we thought ourselves a regular Joe
Otherwise the future revealed
A destiny for us each

> There were prophecies about both: Harry was "the one with power to vanquish the Dark Lord" and Neo was "The One" who would save Zion from the Machines.

Closer to our nemesis
than others we were

> Harry is Voldemort's accidental horcrux. Neo has a ... curious ... relationship with Agent Smith and ends up getting "assimilated" by him.

Entwined with their life
Our deaths were

> Harry was killed by Voldemort, with the intention of getting rid of the extra horcrux. And of course his death had ... further consequences ... for V. Neo sacrificed himself to Agent Smith, rather more finally, in order to destroy Smith.

I marked him, He marked me

> In H.P.'s case, "the Dark Lord shall mark him as his equal". In Neo's, "I marked him" points to the climactic scene of the third movie where Smith assimilates Neo. (It would not be difficult to find "I marked him" candidates for H.P. or to describe that same last scene as "He marked me" for Neo.)

The death of them, incident seemed to be
But not all was revealed
to the four of us it was
A great transfer of power
though unintentional it was

> In H.P.'s case, V. was thought (by many) to have died when he attacked H.P., but that wasn't really the case; in the process of what *did* happen he transferred some of his powers to H.P. In Neo's, Smith thought he was assimilating Neo and taking over his powers, but the poor chap found that that wasn't quite what happened.

Helped us to the end
our mentors did
But not everything of our end
tell us they did
Their own end they met
too very soon
But even then a part
remained to be seen

> Dumbledore was (intermittently) helpful to H.P. from the beginning until his death, and even afterwards (his will, his instructions to Snape, and "King's Cross Station". Dumbledore didn't tell Harry himself that he would have to die or why (he let Snape do it, which ended up happening in a rather roundabout way) and didn't tell even Snape that he expected Harry to survive his own death. This stanza confused me before when I wondered about *The Matrix*, but it turns out to be a reference to the Oracle. To be frank I'm not sure she really counts as a mentor; but indeed she gives Neo some important advice, she doesn't tell him (anything like) everything, she dies (maybe?) between the first and second movies but appears after that, she dies (more completely) when assimilated by Smith, and (thanks to the OP for pointing this out; I'd forgotten) after the Smith-Neo fight it's her body rather than Smith's that's left lying in a ditch.

Alone at last
against our enemy we were
Sure of our fate
we sacrificed ourself

> H.P. in the forest, getting kedavrified by Voldemort. Neo in the third movie, getting assimilated by Smith.

Similar though it seems
Not the same it is
Because here at the end
the difference is revealed
I was resurrected,
But I couldn't do it again

> H.P. returns to life (or maybe never actually quite dies) in the forest. After this he is no longer a horcrux and if killed would just be boringly dead. Neo isn't (so far as we can tell) resurrected at all in any way after the events of the third *Matrix* movie.

I didn't know him, he didn't know me
A verse different we turn out to be

> Our two heroes are from different fictional worlds.

Before/after the end
our mentors did reappear

> Dumbledore has a chat with Harry in "King's Cross Station". The Oracle reappears as a corpse in a ditch.

Do guess our names
Please do it dear.

> Harry James Potter, a.k.a. The Chosen One and Thomas "Neo" Anderson, a.k.a. The One.

Comment: I just got ninjaed! This has to be it. I thought it was too when I thought about marking smith(and thus giving him power and becoming nemesis).

Comment: Yes!! This is the correct answer. The bit about mentors : I am talking about Oracle here. She helped him till the last, but she didn't tell him about his end, what the one is supposed to do(the function of the one : the bit about Zion). She died(or you know ...) before Neo could consult with her one final time after he has chosen to save trinity. She reappears after the end, with Sati. Also at the end of fight, Oracle is lying in place of Smith in the ditch, in the matrix.

Comment: In this bit : 'I was resurrected, But I couldn't do it again' I is Harry. Neo couldn't be resurrected again, but Harry did resurrect(or you know..). I know, my bad I should have been consistent with 'I'.

Comment: At the end of first movie, when Neo jumps into Smith, he is destroyed. I remember the dialogue or maybe I read somewhere that in this process some of Neo's code was copied to Smith, overwriting his code or something of the nature. Sort of the thing with Voldy and Harry. That's what I meant with marked. Matrix events can be interpreted in so  many ways...

Answer (score 4):

Sounds to me like Luke Skywalker and Harry Potter. I think Harry is the one referred to as "I". Details to follow shortly.

... I was writing up some details when OP indicated in comments that H.P. is right but L.S. wrong. So in what follows I shall just write up the H.P. portion. Others are welcome to steal, or refer to, my explanations if they have a different pairing to propose.

We two were the ones
destined to do great things

> There was a prophecy and all.

We started as did Jon
aware of Nothing

> At the start of *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* Harry is living under the Dursleys' stairs and has no idea magic is real.

A world we didn't know
turned out to be our home

> For Harry, the world of magic and wizards.

Waited where we were
with glorious foretellings
While everyone believed
we thought ourselves a regular Joe
Otherwise the future revealed
A destiny for us each

> See above.

Closer to our nemesis
than others we were

> Harry is Voldemort's accidental horcrux.

Entwined with their life
Our deaths were

> Harry was killed by Voldemort, with the intention of getting rid of the extra horcrux. And of course his death had ... further consequences ... for V.

I marked him, He marked me

> In H.P.'s case, "the Dark Lord shall mark him as his equal". I'm not sure what "I marked him" is referring to; the business at the end of HP&tPS has Quirrelmort actually getting marked by H.P.'s hands; getting disincarnated or whatever exactly happened to V. before the story begins might count as being "marked", as might being killed by H.P. at the very end; or it might be some more metaphorical sort of marking.

The death of them, incident seemed to be
But not all was revealed
to the four of us it was
A great transfer of power
though unintentional it was

> In H.P.'s case, V. was thought (by many) to have died when he attacked H.P., but that wasn't really the case; in the process of what *did* happen he transferred some of his powers to H.P.

Helped us to the end
our mentors did
But not everything of our end
tell us they did
Their own end they met
too very soon
But even then a part
remained to be seen

> Dumbledore was (intermittently) helpful to H.P. from the beginning until his death, and even afterwards (his will, his instructions to Snape, and "King's Cross Station". Dumbledore didn't tell Harry himself that he would have to die or why (he let Snape do it, which ended up happening in a rather roundabout way) and didn't tell even Snape that he expected Harry to survive his own death.

Alone at last
against our enemy we were
Sure of our fate
we sacrificed ourself

> H.P. in the forest, getting kedavrified by Voldemort.

Similar though it seems
Not the same it is
Because here at the end
the difference is revealed
I was resurrected,
But I couldn't do it again

> H.P. returns to life (or maybe never actually quite dies) in the forest. After this he is no longer a horcrux and if killed would just be boringly dead.

I didn't know him, he didn't know me
A verse different we turn out to be

> Our two heroes are from different fictional worlds.

Before/after the end
our mentors did reappear

> Dumbledore has a chat with Harry in "King's Cross Station".

Do guess our names
Please do it dear.

> I did, but I got one of them wrong :-). The other one is detailed above.

Comment: Damnit, [that was my idea](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34305767#34305767).

Comment: You got the Harry potter part right. But the first one is incorrect.

Comment: Luke never resurrected. Might be from a point of view he did, but the resurrection in first case is as clear as harry.

Comment: Nice catch with 'I'. Though I should point, Harry was 'marked'. He didnt mark.

Comment: I knew it smelled of Harry...  Lots of stories with parallels where the hero dies at the end instead...  http://io9.gizmodo.com/5683905/everything-harry-potters-been-accused-of-ripping-off

Comment: @IAmInPLS Sorry. Reinvention rather than theft.

Comment: Yes, not theft. And you provided a full answer!

Comment: Awesome description!! The bit with 'mark'. 'He marked me' is for Potter. The other part is for our first hero.

Comment: @Brent Hackers You were right. I dont know why you thought harry didnt fit. The article missed my other hero though

Comment: Regarding "But not everything of our end
tell us they did", I meant that Dumbledore didnt tell harry what he was and what he meant for him to do at the end.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry -- I meant to say something about that and then completely forgot to. Will edit.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan-If you have watched Fantanstic Beasts...It could be [Newt](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Newton_Scamander)

Comment: I haven't. But my understanding is that the two people we're after are from different fictional universes, so if one is Harry Potter then the other can't be Newt Scamander.

Answer (score 1):

LONGSHOT

> Luke and Leia

We two were the ones
 destined to do great things
 We started as did Jon
 aware of Nothing

> they didn't know about their old man or each other or much at all...

A world we didn't know
 turned out to be our home
 Waited where we were
 with glorious foretellings
 While everyone believed
 we thought ourselves a regular Joe
 Otherwise the future revealed
 A destiny for us each

> They were a jedi and force-sensitive super hero ambassador respectively, neither of which knew their original home world

Closer to our nemesis
 then others we were

> close to their nemesis (vader) a family tie *spoiler alert*

Entwined with their life
 Our deaths were
 I marked him, He marked me

> maybe the arm chopping thing?

The death of them, incident seemed to be
 But not all was revealed
 to the four of us it was
 A great transfer of power
 though unintentional it was

> not sure...

Helped us to the end
 our mentors did

> Yoda and Old-Ben

But not everything of our end
 tell us they did

> they liked to keep shtup about the whole family drama thing

Their own end they met
 too very soon

> yep...

But even then a part
 remained to be seen

Alone at last
 against our enemy we were
 Sure of our fate
 we sacrificed ourself
 Similar though it seems
 Not the same it is
 Because here at the end
 the difference is revealed
 I was resurrected,
 But I couldn't do it again

> maybe a reference to loosing an arm, or maybe vader sacrificing himself?  this really is a longshot...

I didn't know him, he didn't know me
 A verse different we turn out to be

> could be luke and leia or luke and vader actually..

Before/after the end
 our mentors did reappear
 Do guess our name
 Please do it dear.

> the mentors are one with the force and manage to speak to luke after death?

Comment: Nice interpretation. But its not the intended answer. Please note 'four'. The two heroes and two nemesis.

Comment: i'm also thinking of this answer lol 7 stanzas symbolizes the 7 episodes lol

Comment: if I made a star wars riddle, I would only make it 4 episodes....sorry...4 stanzas long ;)

Comment: @AnubhavTripathi +1 for disrespecting the prequels

Comment: Like the prequels I do not

Answer (score 0):

Probably also a longshot but here we go

> I think your name is Tyler Durden from the film/novel "Fight Club" - I will give a more detailed explanation if this is the correct answer :)

Comment: I can definitely see why you think that, but, no its not the answer. Our two heroes dont know each other "I didn't know him, he didn't know me". Tyler and narrator knew each other , and while narrator might not have known all about Tyler, Tyler knew everything. A lot of things fit though, nice one.

Comment: I love that all my favorite things Star Wars, GOT, Fight Club etc. are being thought of as answer

Comment: aw, that's too bad, I'll have to keep guessing then :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking to:

> Frodo and Gollum from the Lord of the Rings

They didn't know each other, and they are kind of four, with:

> that ring driving them crazy...

They started out as

> hobbits, which usually don't want to be heroes and know nothing.

`I marked him, he marked me`:

> one bit the other and Frodo did tie Gollum with the elven rope, marking his neck...

And this is movie and litterature.

Comment: hmm. Another one of my favorite. Lord of the Rings. Sadly incorrect though. See the other answer, its half right